# Powershell Unable to Install .MSU files

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to change the proceedure from this site into a script to automate the process. http://www.freenode-windows.org/resources/vista-7/windows-update

When I check Control Panel> System & Security>Windows Update > View Update History-- updates KB3020369, KB3172605, and KB3125574 do not show up as installed. Is there something wrong with my foreach loop?

```
 <########

CONFIGURATION TO STOP WINDOWS UPDATES

#########>

$rmpth = 'c:\windows\softwaredistribution\WuRedir'
$ws = get-service wuauserv

if($ws.Status -eq "Stopped"){
    msg * "Update Service Stopped"
}else{
    stop-service wuauserv -Force
    msg * "Stopping Update Service, Update Service Stopped"
}

if(test-path $rmpth){


    remove-item $rmpth -Force -Confirm:$false

}


<###########

CONFIGURATION TO INSTALL WINDOWS PATCH

###########>

$pathofupdates = @("KB3020369", "KB3172605", "KB3125574")

Foreach($item in $pathofupdates)
{


    $wusainit = "/quiet /norestart C:\temp\Windows /extract C:\temp\Windows\${item}.msu"

    $disminit = "/online /quiet /norestart /add-package /PackagePath:C:\temp\Windows\${disminit}.cab"

    $SB={ Start-Process -FilePath 'wusa.exe' -ArgumentList $wusainit.ToString() -Wait -PassThru }
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SB
    $SB={ Start-Process -FilePath 'dism.exe' -ArgumentList $disminit.ToString() -Wait -PassThru }
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SB

 }
```

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question ("does not look like it actually installs" is pretty vague).

Comment: Thank you, Bill. Changes made. Let me know if it still needs clarification.

Answer (score 1):

foreach loop and .msu file order was the issue. Updates had to be in a certain order. renamed updates to 1.KB3020369.msu, 2.KB3172605.msu, and 3.KB3125574.msu.

Found new method for applying .msu updates on
https://harshilsharma63.wordpress.com/2014/12/27/how-to-install-multiple-msu-windows-update-files-with-powershell-script/

```
<###########

CONFIGURATION TO INSTALL WINDOWS PATCH

###########>

$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$dir = (Get-Item -Path $dir -Verbose).FullName
Foreach($item in (ls $dir *.msu -Name))
{
    echo $item
    $item = $dir + "\" + $item
    wusa $item /quiet /norestart | Out-Null
}
```